# How to convert Json (from JIRA's webhook) to Custom Java object

Tags: json, jira, webhooks

I have some Java REST APIs which will be invoked via JIRA Webhook configuration.
Now, when JIRA webhook is invoking REST API, there are large no. of custom fields (like customfield_17270) which contain useful data.

For example, I have configured "Create Issue" event in JIRA webhook i.e. whenever any issue will be created in JIRA, my REST API will be invoked. While creating issue in JIRA, for example, there is a field named "Issue Title" whose value is "XXX". In JSON payload, ideally key-value pair should be "Issue Title":"XXX" but it is like "Custom_Field109":"XXX".

Now the problem is how to map this dynamic JSON to Java Object.

Is there anyone who has faced similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you receive the webhook, you'll need to map each custom id (e.g. `customfield_10070`) to it's name by querying the [field JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/field-getFields) at **GET: /rest/api/2/field**

...which will give you something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "issuetype",
        "name": "Issue Type",
        "custom": false,
        "orderable": true,
        "navigable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "clauseNames": [
            "issuetype",
            "type"
        ],
        "schema": {
            "type": "issuetype",
            "system": "issuetype"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "customfield_10070",
        "name": "FAQ Necessary?",
        "custom": true,
        "orderable": true,
        "navigable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "clauseNames": [
            "cf[10070]",
            "FAQ Necessary?"
        ],
        "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:radiobuttons",
            "customId": 10070
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

You should then easily be able to iterate over the fields from the webhook JSON and map the custom field id to its display name.

Comment: Good to know that There is REST API to get actual fields name. BTW, i was able to coordinate with JIRA internal team and they provided me custom fields mapping to their display name by retrieving data from JIRA database tables.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to discuss this issue with JIRA internal team and they provided me custom fields mapping to their JIRA display name. 
Basically, when we receive Json keys like Custom_field109 then it means 109 is internal database id for this attribute.
Now, based on given mapping, I parsed JSON to get required keys and then through Jackson library, I was able to map JSOn to Java.

Comment: Can you provide the code for parsing the JSON and creating the Java Objects?

Comment: If this is the solution to the question, please mark it by clicking on the tick. This will mark the question as answered. Thank you.